# Rails - How to create relationships between objects in the same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a family album application. A user can sign on and create a "Family" object. Once the family object is created, the user can then populate the family with "Members." The application allows you to create one member as a standalone object. After the first member has been created, all later members must be created from an existing member's show page. When they are created, the member being created needs to establish how it is related to the current member (the show page). Relationships should be 'parent', 'child' or 'sibling.'

I am having some extreme difficultly figuring out how to do this. The solution needs to do BOTH of these things:

1. When a new 'member' is created, both objects will have a record of the new relationship.
2. The type of relationship needs to be specified. It can't JUST be "member" belongs to "member." It needs to be "member" #1 is "member"#2's parent.

Right now, this is the schema for the member table:

```
create_table "members", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "first_name"
t.string   "last_name"
t.string   "birthplace"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.integer  "family_id"
t.integer  "parent_id"
t.integer  "child_id"
t.integer  "sibling_id"
end
```

I have NOT established a has_many relationship between members yet. When a new member is created, I simply make that new member's "parent_id" or "child_id" or "sibling_id" equal the id of the current member being shown (again, form is in member show page)

```
        <%= form_for [@family, @new] do |m| %> 
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= m.text_field :first_name, placeholder: "First Name", class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= m.text_field :last_name, placeholder: "Last Name", class: 'form-control' %> 
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= m.text_field :birthplace, placeholder: "Birthplace", class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Parent</label>
            <%= m.select :child_id, @members.collect { |m| [ m.full_name, m.id ] }, include_blank: true %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= m.submit "Add", class:"btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
```

This is a very silly way to do it imo. Ideally, I want to have a set of radio buttons that say "Parent", "Sibling" and "Child." The user must click on one of the buttons, but can only click on one of them. When the form is submitted, the relationship between the current member and the new member is then established according to which radio button was clicked. My current strategy does not update the current member at all. The relationship can only be referenced in one direction. This method also requires a selection of the other member... which is not what I want.

Should I be using has_many through tables? Help!

Comment: `My current method does not update the current member at all` which method you talking about? and why is it not working, any errors or validation? also share your model

Comment: I didn't mean a literal method. I just meant my strategy. Sorry. Poor wording.

Answer (score 2):

You should indeed be using `has_many_through` because I would imagine you need to support multiple relationships... a parent can have more than one child so having a `child_id` in the parent isn't enough to handle that condition.

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :parent_links, class_name: 'ParentChildLink', foreign_key: :child_id
  has_many :parents, through: :parent_links, class_name: 'Member', foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :child_links, class_name: 'ParentChildLink',  foreign_key: :parent_id
  has_many :children, through: :parent_links, class_name: 'Member', foreign_key: :child_id
end
```

The 'parent_child_links' table would have

```
class ParentChildLink < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Member', foreign_key: :parent_id
  belongs_to :child, class_name: 'Member', foreign_key: :child_id
end
```

And now through the magic of rails you can do...

```
tommy = Member.create(name: 'Tommy')
peter = Member.create(name: 'Peter')

peter.children << tommy
```

Comment: This is very helpful! How would I handle this on the form side? I am still learning to use this type of relationship. Thank you!